# LeafletJS markers move on zoom

Tags: dictionary, leaflet

Using LeafletJS which is ace, well until now :P We don't have a JSON object or anything, so I am taking the values out of the HTML (title, latlng) and creating markers. Generally that works ok, however there is an issue with the plotting of them. When the map is really zoomed in they seem to be ok, but when you zoom out (like the map is initially), they are way off. They then move on zoom.

So, what am I doing wrong?

http://jsbin.com/edegox/1
http://jsbin.com/edegox/1/edit

Cheers
Tom

Answer (score 51):

The solution to this is quite simple. Leads should have posted it.

when your markers are moving around your map it's because the map doesn't know the size of your marker and/or it doesn't know the point of your marker that marks the location.

your marker icon code might look like this:

```
var locationIcon = L.icon({iconUrl:'location_marker_icon.png'});
```

now, let's suppose your image is 24px wide and 36px tall. To keep your marker from moving around, you simply specify the size of the marker, and the "anchor point"...

```
var locationIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl:'location_marker_icon.png',
    iconSize: [24,36],
    iconAnchor: [12,36]
});
```

This will make the center pixel on the bottom represent the exact lat/lng point you specified the marker for, and it will keep it anchored there!

Answer (score 36):

Given an icon that looks like this, with an overall size of 98px wide by 114px tall:

[image]

- `iconSize` will be `[98, 114]`. This is the overall size of the icon.
- Your `iconAnchor` will be `[49, 114]`. The icon anchors first numeral can be calculated by taking the first numeral in the `iconSize` and dividing by 2 (i.e., `98 ÷ 2 = 49`)

If you wanted to use this icon example, your final code should look like this:

```
var locationIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl:'location_marker_icon.png',
  iconSize: [98, 114],
  iconAnchor: [49, 114]
});
```

Here's a Gist example you can test with (I highlighted the lines in question) https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe19008c911e1e6b6490#file-index-html-L38-L44