# leaflet How can I hook markers on map coordinates

Tags: leaflet, markers

On Leaflet, the custom markers are not hooked to the coordinates but move with the scale of the map.

How can I fix this ?

```html
 <html>
     <head>
         <!-- Library Leaflet -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css"
integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ=="
crossorigin=""/>
         <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"
integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log=="
crossorigin=""></script>
         <style>
             #map {
             position: absolute;
             }
         </style>
     </head>
     <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" >
         <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             window.onload= function() {
                 var lat =43.6;
                 var lon = 6.99;
                 var map = L.map("map").setView([43.6,6.99],18) ;
             var lyrOSM= L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?') ;
             lyrOSM.addTo(map);

             // create icon
                 var myIcon = L.icon( {
                     iconUrl: 'C:/Users/ericire/Pictures/map markers/pin_red.png',
                     iconSize: [32, 32],
                     shadowSize: [12, 10],
                     iconAnchor: [16, 32],
                     popupAnchor: [5, -5]
                 } );
                var myIcon2 = L.icon( {
                     iconUrl: 'C:/Users/ericire/Pictures/map markers/pin_red.png',
                     iconSize: [32, 32],
                     shadowSize: [12, 10],
                     iconAnchor: [0, 0],
                     popupAnchor: [5, -5]
                 } );

                 //markers
                 var marker = L.marker( [location.lat, location.lon ], { icon: myIcon } ).addTo(map);
                 var marker = L.marker(  [location.lat, location.lon ], { icon: myIcon2 } ).addTo(map);

             }

         </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875438/leafletjs-markers-move-on-zoom/32157984#32157984

Comment: Hi
that's right now
thanks a lot