# Assigning positions to leaflet markers in a loop

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to populate the positions for the markers in leaflet. but when my map shows up the markers are all over the place and don't match the data that is actually coming in. Also, when I zoom in and out the markers appear to change position as well. below is the part of the code for markers. I wanted to know what I am going wrong or if there is any other way to do the same.

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rss/cities/", success: function (result) {
            //console.log(result);
            cities = result;
            Object.entries(result)
                .forEach(keyValuePair => {
                    // Push to HTML
                     console.log(keyValuePair[1])
                    L.marker(keyValuePair[1],
                        {
                            icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
                                icon: 'cog', markerColor: 'darked', prefix: 'fa', iconColor: 'red',
                                spin: true,
                            })
                        }).addTo(mymap);

                });

        }
    });
```

The format of the data that is coming in is as follows:

```
{"Bali":[48.8566101,2.3514992],"Born":[51.0448394,5.83763311859952],"Doha":[25.3014957,51.4996673988223],.......}
```

Comment: FYI. Your latlong for Bali looks incorrect: https://www.latlong.net/place/bali-indonesia-3445.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875438/leafletjs-markers-move-on-zoom