# Leaflet layer gets malformed on zoom out

Tags: leaflet

In this leaflet map once I zoom out (all the icons of) the layer turns into a small rectangle. It seems the layer is not stretched over the entire portview anymore.

http://skiweather.eu/alpenwetter/

[image]

Comment: Please share your code. I tried the link provided, the issue I saw was that the markers are moving when zooming - which could be down to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875438/leafletjs-markers-move-on-zoom

Comment: the dimensions were there, but it was the position relative which turned out to be the problem (with the new leaflet lib). Thanx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LeafletJS markers move on zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875438/leafletjs-markers-move-on-zoom)